# 'Binomial Expansion' - How to find value of term in expression with given coefficients?

Tags: binomial-theorem

I have been given this question:

**"Find the value of $c$ if, in the expansion of $(cx + 2)^3$, the coefficient of $x$ is $24$"**

To solve this question, I have tried using the 'General Term In Binomial Expression' formula as well as using the pascals triangle and expanding the brackets by hand and then adding in the coefficient, but every attempt still has many square's and cubed numbers remaining.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site.  To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs.  For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$.  You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each term in the binomial expansion is of the form ${3\choose k}(cx)^k2^{3-k}$, and you want the term with $x^1$ in it, so the $k=1$ term. Then you get $3\cdot cx\cdot 2^2=12cx$. So you have $c=2$.